# How to autowire repository in Swing application

Tags: java, spring, swing

I am attempting to create a Swing application using Spring Boot. In the root of my packages I have the main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class)
                .headless(false)
                .run(args);

        System.out.println("Contains personRepository: " + ctx.containsBeanDefinition("personRepository"));

        EventQueue.invokeLater(() ->
        {
            ApplicationFrame appFrame = ctx.getBean(ApplicationFrame.class);
            appFrame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

As I understand, @SpringBootApplication should find any spring components in packages under it. When Application is run, it starts ApplicationFrame:

```
@Component
public class ApplicationFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame
{
    @Autowired PersonRepository personRepository;

    /**
    * Creates new form ApplicationFrame
    */
    public ApplicationFrame()
    {
        initComponents();
        System.out.println("personRepository = " + personRepository);
    }
}
```

PersonRepository is in a package under the root and is annotated with @Repository.

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {}
```

When I run this, it returns:

```
Contains personRepository: true
personRepository = null
```

So Application can find the repository as a bean, but ApplicationFrame cannot autowire it. Do I create ApplicationFrame the wrong way or is there something else that I'm missing here?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: A good first step is always to replace field injection with constructor injection. See what happens if you do that.

Comment: That seemed to do the trick. Thanks! Can you tell me why, or point me at a resource that explains it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you have to remove `@Repository` annotation from repository class since this is a redundant annotation. Instead of this you should annotate `Application` class with `@EnableJpaRepositories` - it's more convenient way of working with Spring Data.

About your output: you see `personRepository = null` in the log because this log statement is located within a constructor. At this moment, the field value is null.

In your case you use field injection - this means that Spring autowires beans after object constructing. So nothing wrong with `ApplicationFrame` class, only with an output.

To see the correct output you can use constructor-based injection:

```
@Component
public class ApplicationFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame
{
    private final PersonRepository personRepository;

    /**
    * Creates new form ApplicationFrame
    */
    public ApplicationFrame(final PersonRepository pr)
    {
        personRepository = pr;

        initComponents();
        System.out.println("personRepository = " + personRepository);
    }
}
```